How can I log in to a scratch org directly with the sf CLI (no DevHub)
I have a user account in a scratch org and I need to log in to it via the sf CLI so I can deploy some resources.
For some reasons which are hopefully temporary, I do not have an account in the DevHub org, so the usual methods for logging in don't seem to apply.
I tried using sf org login web. On the login screen, I had to click the "Use Custom Domain" button, otherwise it wouldn't recognize my credentials:

The credentials were accepted, but then the browser would error out with AuthCodeExchangeError:

and the CLI with authentication failure:

No further explanation. I don't see anything obvious in the documentation that I'm missing. Is this even possible?


Is this even possible?

Yes, this is possible.
I'm not sure if or where it's documented, but the trick is to use the --instance-url flag with the login web command. Something about clicking that "Use Custom Domain" button seems to break the oauth flow, but if you include the domain explicitly then the oauth flow will work.
I also recommend using the --set-default flag if you intend to perform additional actions, such as deployments, to the org.
So the full command would look something like:
sf org login web --instance-url https://<mydomain>.my.salesforce.com --set-default

If you are logging in to a scratch org, then your My Domain probably includes .scratch added at the end, e.g.:
https://random-word-9999-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com
                                -------

That's pretty easy to miss and might account for some trouble when logging in to your scratch org.
